# How to use path variable in JSON path

Tags: javascript, json, variables, path

I'm trying to use a **path variable** in a **JSON path**.

My problem is that my variable is added as a new key to the JSON object instead of replacing my path.

My Example Code

```
Data = {
    first:{
        "Name":"John",
        "Age":"43"
    }
}

let path = "first.name"
let value = "Jan"

Data[path] = value
console.log(Data)
```

Current Output

```
Data = {
    first:{
        "Name":"John",
        "Age":"43"
    },
    "first.name": "Jan",
}
```

Expected Output

```
Data = {
    first:{
        "Name":"Jan",
        "Age":"43"
    }  
}
```

Is there a way to solve this? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script shall do what you want with an object (if I understood your problem well), until you provide it with the correct path :-)

```js
function setAttr(obj, path, value){
    let objCopy = obj;
    let attrNameArr = path.split('.');
    for(let idx = 0; idx < attrNameArr.length-1; idx++){
        objCopy = objCopy[attrNameArr[idx]];
    }
    objCopy[attrNameArr[attrNameArr.length-1]] = value;
    return obj;
}


Data = {
    first:{
        "Name":"John",
        "Age":"43"
    }
}

setAttr(Data, "first.Name", "Jan");
console.log(Data);
```

it basically changes the attributes of object using the fact that objCopy and obj share the same reference.